# averaging of data using apache spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using python
I'm receiving json dictionaries through kafka into spark stream,
JSON is like {"a":10}{"a":20} (One dict means one kafka message), key will be "a" always but how much dictionaries, that is not sure.
Now I want average of 10 and 20 in above case.
As per the my knowledge averageByKey may be useful.
But how to use, that I dont know.
Any help would be great!

Thank you for reading 
.
.
.
.
.

**Update**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

def createContext():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_02")
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)

    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'localhost:2181', 'spark-streaming-consumer', {'':1})
    raw = kafkaStream.map(lambda kafkaS: kafkaS[1])
    clean = raw.map(lambda v: json.loads(v))
    print (dir(clean))
    clean.pprint()

    add=clean.map(lambda xs: ('Total',xs['hello'])).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    add.pprint()

    count_var = clean.count()
    count_var.pprint()
    average = add.map(lambda tpl: tpl[1]/float(60))
    average.pprint()
    return ssc

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate('/path/checkpoint_v'+sys.argv[1],lambda: createContext())
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Now

```
 in above program I'm getting add.pprint() output as below for example:
Stream is like:
{u'hello': 26}
{u'hello': 28}
{u'hello': 31}
{u'hello': 35}
{u'hello': 40}
{u'hello': 46}

>('Total',206) 

and output of count_var.pprint() as below for example:
> 6

The question is, in below line 

> average = add.map(lambda tpl: tpl[1]/float(60))
I want to use value of count_var.pprint()(which is 6) instead of static value 60

So how can I use stream object as integer in above operation
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to map your event to some processable type, for example tuple. Then you can use just classic "map -> reduceByKey -> map" to calculate the average like this:

```
import json

ssc = StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, 1)
dstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ['topic'], client_configuration, 
              valueDecoder=lambda s: json.loads(s.decode('ascii')))

def map_event(raw):
    item = list(raw[1].items())[0]
    return (item[0], (1, item[1]))

dstream.map(map_event).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1])) \
    .map(lambda r: (r[0], float(r[1][1]) / r[1][0])) \
    .pprint()

ssc.start()
```